# Microsoft user not getting stored in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, azure-active-directory

I have setup microsoft auth with firebase & this package: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_oauth

this is the signup code:

```dart
Future<void> signUpTest() async {
    User user = await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow("microsoft.com",
        ["email openid"], {'tenant': 'someId'});
    print(user);
  }
```

it goes back to my app but i get this error:

```dart
 [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(FirebaseAuthError, The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Error getting access token from microsoft.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://share-files-26506.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_client&error_description=AADSTS7000215:%20Invalid%20client%20secret%20is%20provided.%0D%0ATrace%20ID:%209a97073f-e46b-4189-a835-480869783900%0D%0ACorrelation%20ID:%203417d495-65f3-4249-866b-0c7d4949a21c%0D%0ATimestamp:%202021-03-12%2010:18:18Z&timestamp=2021-03-12%2010:18:18Z&trace_id=9a97073f-e46b-4189-a835-480869783900&correlation_id=3417d495-65f3-4249-866b-0c7d4949a21c&error_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code%3D7000215, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=401, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 
OK
E/flutter ( 5819): 
E/flutter ( 5819): , contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], cookieList=[]}} ], com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Error getting access token from microsoft.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://share-files-26506.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_client&error_description=AADSTS7000215:%20Invalid%20client%20secret%20is%20provided.%0D%0ATrace%20ID:%209a97073f-e46b-4189-a835-480869783900%0D%0ACorrelation%20ID:%203417d495-65f3-4249-866b-0c7d4949a21c%0D%0ATimestamp:%202021-03-12%2010:18:18Z&timestamp=2021-03-12%2010:18:18Z&trace_id=9a97073f-e46b-4189-a835-480869783900&correlation_id=3417d495-65f3-4249-866b-0c7d4949a21c&error_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code%3D7000215, httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=401, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK
E/flutter ( 5819):
E/flutter ( 5819): , contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], cookieList=[]}} ]
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzte.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:28)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzum.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:9)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzun.zzk(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:1)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuk.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:25)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztb.zzk(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:1)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzpc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:2)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzur.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:24)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzub.zzd(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:4)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzpj.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:4)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztf.zzd(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:5)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzrr.zzd(Unknown Source:15)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzrq.accept(Unknown Source:6)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zacj.doExecute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:2)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaf.zac(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:6)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zac(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:167)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:139)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:105)
E/flutter ( 5819):      at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-
```

any help?

Comment: Hi did you look into my answer? Any updates?

Comment: i had already fixed it, marked as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message has stated it clearly:

`AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.`

Please kindly check it. You can create a new client secret for test.